# IBM MQ python3 module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ibm-mq, pymqi

Is anyone aware of an IBM Websphere MQ module compatible with python3? pymqi doesn’t seem compatible and the author seems unconcerned with that fact.

Comment: Well, since PyMQI is open source, do what you need to do to it to make it compatible with Python 3.

Comment: rich did you ever find a solution to this? i have the same issue

Comment: Did anyone find the solution to this?

Comment: A users provided and the maintainer recently merged in 3.5 support, see "[Python 3.5 and 2.7 #60](https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/issues/60)

Comment: Hi Rich, the py3mqi fork has not been maintained since it was put out there.  The original pymqi has supported Python 3 since 1.8 (around 2 years ago).  Users of py3mqi keep coming to the pymqi github site with issues.  Could you please accept the answer provided by @Seyf to help point more people to the current state that pymqi does support Python 3.

Comment: @JoshMc done so (sorry @max) I’m no longer using MQ but i get what you mean

Comment: Great, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pymqi](https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi) v1.10.1 compatible with python 3.x (tested with 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

Answer (score 2):

For using pymqi in python3 you can use the module 'py3mqi'.

```
pip install py3mqi
```

You are also more than welcome to check my wrapper for 
the pymqi in python3 https://github.com/Hyaxia/pymqiwm

Good luck!

Comment: Note the maintainer of the original pymqi recently merged in 3.5 support, see "[Python 3.5 and 2.7 #60](https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/issues/60)".